# uninitialized constant Fog::AWS::CredentialFetcher / fog / fog-aws / asset-sync gem error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, fog, asset-sync

I just started getting this error:

```
Unable to load application: NameError: uninitialized constant Fog::AWS::CredentialFetcher
```

No changes except to add omniauth-freshbooks gem (and change its client_options: 'site') beforehand - before deployment to Heroku.  Belatedly realized that I'd updated gems betwix and between.  The ones updated were bundler, minitest-reporters and spring.

Known error / appears unresolved: https://github.com/fog/fog-aws/issues/83

Tried the recommended 'fix' - below - but it isn't working with Heroku:

```
Damm. Try changing this:

gem "fog", "~>1.20", require: "fog/aws/storage"
gem "asset_sync"

to:

gem "fog-aws"
gem "asset_sync"
```

(a) I was not requiring 'fog/aws/storage';  (b) gem 'asset-sync' wasn't installed; (c) fog is required by carrierwave and paperclip - or I'd simply remove all three gems.

The recommend fix doesn't work for me.  Any thoughts / ideas / workarounds would be appreciated.

Thanks, Doug

Answer (score 0):

I was hit by the same problem and, as long as `asset_sync` is not actively maintained, @paulrnash started a new fork called `neo-asset_sync`. I'm using it in production with no issues.

You can configure it like this in your Gemfile.

```
gem 'neo-asset_sync', github: 'paulrnash/asset_sync'
gem 'fog-aws'
```